# PHP explode multi line text in text file

Tags: php, laravel, api, explode

I have a text file and the data inside is:

```
john,male,20,200,174
joe,male,24,157,166
bea,female,18,153,160
edd,male,30,180,180
```

I am using Laravel and so I have the folder containing this text file in storage/app/upload.
In my controller this is my code:

```
public function readfile() 
    {
        $file = Storage::get('upload/test.txt');        
        $array = explode(',', $file);
        print_r($array);
    }
```

the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => john
    [1] => male
    [2] => 20
    [3] => 200
    [4] => 174
joe
    [5] => male
    [6] => 24
    [7] => 157
    [8] => 166
bea
    [9] => female
    [10] => 18
    [11] => 153
    [12] => 160
edd
    [13] => male
    [14] => 30
    [15] => 180
    [16] => 180
)
```

what I NEED to happen is this:

```
Array
(
     [0] => john,male,20,200,174
     [1] => joe,male,24,157,166
     [2] => bea,female,18,153,160
     [3] => edd,male,30,180,180
)
```

I am still new to this and I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry just got back. i will check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public function readfile() 
    {
        $file = Storage::get('upload/test.txt');        
        $array = explode(PHP_EOL, $file);
        print_r($array);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, it worked!!!! i did this already but with just return response, so it should be print_r if i want it in an array. THANKS again!!!

Comment: Orite. Please mark as answer if this fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

To get array of arrays  (lines-comma separation) try

```
public function readfile() 
    $file = Storage::get('upload/test.txt');
    $lines = explode("\n", $file);
    $array = array_map(function($line) {
        return explode(',', $line);
    }, $lines);
    print_r($array);
}
```

If you want to get only array of lines then it is in `$lines`. Working example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8a9d010f8024db6ff89426a66ed49b23dcee2ce3)

Comment: the first one works. thanks anyway . i appreciate the help

Comment: hmmmm. what if i want to change the index. instead of [0] , [1], [2]. how to change it to string?

Comment: @jediArvin this is separate question - find or ask it on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code

```
public function readfile() 
{
    $file = Storage::get('upload/test.txt');   
    $fileData = [];
    while (!$file->eof()) {
        $fileData[] = $file->fgetcsv(",");
    }
    print_r($fileData);
}
```

Comment: the first one works. thanks anyway . i appreciate the help

Comment: Please vote as accepted if it works fine. It would help others to find the correct answer. Thanks for your response,